# slickGoTo method in slick slider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using the slick slider, and multiple slides are shown with the center mode.
I'm using a button to hide a slide when I click on the button, but when the shown slides are all hidden it doesn't show the other slides. I tried to use slicktogo function to force it to slide but it's not working

that's the code I use

```
$('.mini-buttons .check-o').on('click', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.pops').fadeOut(400);
    var slideIndex = $('.pops').index();
    console.log(slideIndex);
    $('.products-list').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex - 1));
  }, 200);
});

$('.products-list').slick({
  speed: 1000,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  focusOnSelect: false,
  variableWidth: false,
  prevArrow:
    '<div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>',
  nextArrow:
    '<div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>',
});

$('.products-list').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToScroll', 6, true);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `slickRemove` to remove your slides in a way that the Slick slideshow will recognize?

Comment: I tried it but the slideshow  won't recognize